# How can I mock a SimpleXMLElement object using PHPUnit?

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit, simplexml

To unit test a class I'd like to create a mock of a `SimpleXMLElement` object. Unfortunately I can't figure out how to do this. I'd usually go about this as follows:

```
class XmlTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testSimpleXmlMock()
    {
        $mock = $this
            ->getMockBuilder('SimpleXMLElement')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();

        $this->assertInstanceOf('SimpleXMLElement', $mock);
    }
}
```

This formula works when mocking other classes (e.g. `DOMDocument`), but it doesn't work for `SimpleXMLElement`. Running the test produces the following error:

```
1) XmlTest::testSimpleXmlMock
unserialize(): Node no longer exists
```

I'm using PHPUnit 4.1.3. I've tried various combinations of options on the mock builder, including passing an XML string as a parameter to the constructor, but can't find a combination that works.

How can I create a mock `SimpleXMLElement` object?

Answer (score 3):

The class "SimpleXMLElement" is an implementation of "Traversable" interface. You can easily mock it and the dependency injection can be based on the interface... it is not the ideal solution but it works.

```
private function getMockSimpleXmlElement()
{
    $mock = $this
        ->getMockBuilder('Traversable')
        ->getMock();

    return $mock;
}
```

Otherwise you should create a class which wraps the class and functionality of "SimpleXMLElement" you need... and then inject the wrapper class.